# Cannot configure autopep formatter for python

Tags: python, output, settings, formatter, autopep8

I have python 3.11.4 and I am trying to use the formatter extension called autopep8.

When I right click on my python file I choose format with autopep, but formatting doesn't happen. Can someone please point me in the right direction? Thank you

In my settings.json I included the following per the extension doc:

```
"[python]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "ms-python.autopep8",
        "editor.formatOnSave": true
}
```

I have tried disabling the extension and enabling it again, restarting my computer, closing out of vscode, using another formatter called "black," but I wasn't able to get that one working either. I attached a view of my output logs for autopep because I read somewhere online that this could be useful.

By the way, I have another formatter called prettier in the same editor that I use for javascript.

[outputlog]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sktkb.png)